# Is there a difference between $(e.currentTarget) and $(this)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there any difference between the following two methods? Is #1 faster than #2 ?

#1

```
$('#selector').on('click',function(){
  $(this)...
  // do stuff with clicked element
})
```

and

#2

```
$('#selector').on('click',function(e){
  $(e.currentTarget)....
  // do stuff with clicked element
})
```

Comment: Reading the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) should have given you the answer.

Comment: This bug report is relevant : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11756 . Officially use `this` since they assume that's what 98% are doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like they are equivalent in most cases, though "this" seems easier to type

according to http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

> `event.currentTarget`
>
> This property will typically be equal to the `this` of the function.
>
> If you are using [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or another form of scope manipulation,
>   `this` will be equal to whatever context you have provided, not
>   `event.currentTarget`

Comment: Thank you for this answer -- I wanted to change an event handler to use a ECMA5 .bind() call, but couldn't figure out how to get both the original .this context and the new .this context.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, they would do the same thing. But e.currentTarget will always refer to what was clicked on, whereas $(this) will grab the selector you're applying the handler to.