# Check the form element triggered at onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

I have a js function inside a web page that trap the position of the click on it. I had to implement it in a way that is recognized if the page contain a form element, and, if so, do a check as to whether that the click that I'm recording is made on one at random form element or not. 
I got up to check the form and to learn its elements, but I do not know how to check if the click is made ​​on a single element:

```
$('*').on('mousedown', function (e) {
 // make sure the event isn't bubbling
 if (e.target != this) {
    return;
 }
 // do something with the click somewhere
 // for example, get the coordinates:
 x = e.pageX;
 y = e.pageY;
 pa = $(location).attr('href');
 //Window dimension
 var width = $(window).width();
 //var width = $getWidth();
 var height = $(window).height();

 //Check if page contain a form
 var elementF =  document.querySelectorAll('form');
 var fname = '';
 var elements = '';
 for (var i=0; i<elementF.length; i++){
  fname = elementF[i].id;
  elements = document.forms[fname].elements;
  for (x=0; x<elements.length; x++){
    //Now i need to check if element is clicked or not
  }
}
```

Comment: whoa... You're probably just saying you want to use an id? You would give your form an id attribute, and then use `document.getElementById(id_here)`.

Comment: I already know if the form exists or not, and I already know all the id of its elements, I need to know if the click that I'm recording is done on one of these items or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is binding a mousedown event to every element on the page. This will be resource intensive and should not be necessary. Also, since it's bound everywhere, the `if (e.target !== this){ return; }` does prevent it from firing a million times whenever you mousedown on something, but also prevents it from bubbling. Just let it bubble and use `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` to tell stuff apart. There shouldn't be any reason to do `$('*').on("mousedown")`

Why can't you just do this?

```
$("form").on("click", function(e){
    // e.currentTarget will be the form element capturing the click

    console.log( $(e.currentTarget).html() );

    // e.target will be whatever element you clicked on
    // so you can do whatever you want with it

    console.log( $(e.target).text() );

    // All your handler code here
});
```

Some possibly helpful stuff

- http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/
- [Is there a difference between $(e.currentTarget) and $(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632426/is-there-a-difference-between-e-currenttarget-and-this)
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('*').on('mousedown', function (e) {
  var elementClicked = e.target.nodeName;
  console.log("element: " + elementClicked)
})
```